# Not able to fix width of datatable columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

We are using datatables in our application.
Can someone pls suggest how to set width of columns inside datatable.

Here is the basic configuration:

```
WATable =   $('#dtAssignment').dataTable({
            "sScrollY": "150px",
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "sPaginationType": "two_button",
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "iDisplayLength": DefaultRecordsPerPage,
            "aLengthMenu": [[100, 250, 500], [100, 250, 500]],
            "sDom": 'Trti<"row"<"two columns" l><"seven-by-five columns"<"#dvGoto">><"offset-by-seven" p>>',
            "aoColumns": dtAssignmentData.template,
            "aoColumnDefs": dtAssignmentData.columnDefs,
             "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
```

We are getting aoColumns & aoColumnDefs data from ASP.NET MVC application. Below is the sample JSON data from server.

```
{"columnDefs":[{"sTitle":"Description","aTargets":"[0]","sWidth":"220px","sName":null,"sType":null},{"sTitle":"User ID","aTargets":"[1]","sWidth":"50px","sName":null,"sType":null},{"sTitle":"Date Added","aTargets":"[2]","sWidth":"80px","sName":null,"sType":null}],"template":[{"mDataProp":"Description","fnRender":null,"sClass":null,"mRender":null,"sWidth":null},{"mDataProp":"CreatedBy","fnRender":null,"sClass":null,"mRender":null,"sWidth":null},{"mDataProp":"CreationDate","fnRender":null,"sClass":null,"mRender":null,"sWidth":null}],"aaData":[{ ... BLAH..BLAH..BLAH
```

Datatable is auto sizing columns even after setting "bAutoWidth": false and setting sWidth for each column.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to adjust the data that you're sending. It doesn't make sense to set both `aoColumns` and `aoColumnDefs`. Use `aoColumns` only if you're sending information for all columns.
- You're setting `"sWidth":null` in one option and `"sWidth":"220px"` in another which is confusing.
- Avoid using deprecated [`fnRender`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#fnRender) option, [`mRender`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#mRender) option is recommended to use instead.
- Add the following CSS rule to avoid table to use 100% of page width.

  ```
  table.dataTable {
    width:auto;
  }
  ```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ntp5eda/) for code and demonstration.